# Change event.target to a new location (url) instead of a new class

Tags: javascript, event-handling

How can I make the event to change url instead of adding a class with event.target?

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>taphold demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
  html, .ui-mobile, .ui-mobile body {
    height: 85px;
  }
  .ui-mobile, .ui-mobile .ui-page {
    min-height: 85px;
  }
  #nav {
    font-size: 200%;
    width:17.1875em;
    margin:17px auto 0 auto;
  }
  #nav a {
    color: #777;
    border: 2px solid #777;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.3em;
  }
  #nav a:hover {
    color: #999;
    border-color: #999;
    background: #eee;
  }
  #nav a.selected,
  #nav a.selected:hover {
    color: #0a0;
    border-color: #0a0;
    background: #afa;
  }
  div.box {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: #108040;
  }
  div.box.taphold {
    background-color: #7ACEF4;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Long press the square for 750 milliseconds to see the above code applied:</h3>
<div class="box">Link</div>

<script>
$(function(){
  $( "div.box" ).bind( "taphold", tapholdHandler );

  function tapholdHandler( event ){
    $( event.target ).addClass( "taphold" );
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I Tap and hold the div box with the code above it will change the color (add a new class) but if I want it to change to eg. url: www.google.com instead..

How can I implement this.

I have tried changing:

```
$( event.target ).addClass( "taphold" );
```

to:

```
$( event.target ).window.location.href='http://www.google.com';
```

but this doesn't work.

Anyone to help??   :-)

*Kenneth*

Comment: Have you tried just `window.location.href='http://www.google.com';`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your function to navigate to your chosen url. There is no need for you to use `event`.

```
  function tapholdHandler() {
    window.location.href='http://www.google.com';
  }
```

Comment: Lol.. Sometimes it's just the obvoius solution that you can't see.. :-D  Thanks for the quick answer.